# Apache Spark Java - Pi Estimation Example Compilation issues

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to Apache Spark. From https://spark.apache.org/examples.html, I tried to compile the following snippet

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(NUM_SAMPLES);
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i++) {
  l.add(i);
}

long count = sc.parallelize(l).filter(i -> {
  double x = Math.random();
  double y = Math.random();
  return x*x + y*y < 1;
}).count();

System.out.println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / NUM_SAMPLES);
```

However, when I compiled this code, I noticed that the parallelize method takes three params instead of 1. So tried this

```
JavaRDD<Integer> distData = sc.parallelize(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(l), 2,
                scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Integer.class));
```

But that's throwing another exception

```
Error:(38, 51) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T,A,T exist so that org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD<T> conforms to org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD<java.lang.Integer>
```

Not sure what's the right way to compile that code and run the example successfully.

Spark version used: 2.1.0

Comment: Can you please clarify which version of Spark and Java do you use? There is a parallelize method that takes 1 argument: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4f4829b4ae261a9fd656fbf1928e6440d31f8d8c/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.scala#L144

``  def parallelize[T](list: java.util.List[T]): JavaRDD[T] ``

There is also a Java example in the spark repository that uses the parallelize method with 2 arguments:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5e79ae3b40b76e3473288830ab958fc4834dcb33/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/JavaSparkPi.java

Comment: Updated the version in the question. Will check that link. I need an example with to parallelize using 3 arguments.

Comment: I am sorry to say, but I am pretty sure you won't find such method. Look at the documentation:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html
Also if you check the source code of JavaSparkContext and it's parent class SparkContext, you cannot see such method.

Comment: ok, somehow in my Intellijdea I keep getting that signature when I copy pasted the code in the above link. The following is the grade dependency - compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.10', version: '1.5.2'